# My Google Drive keeps going offline when I upload or download

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, microsoft-edge

When I upload or download a file (size irrelevant), Google Drive goes offline within 2 seconds. This is repeatable, and occurred suddenly beginning around Dec-09/10. I can longer upload / download any file since.  My Windows 10 is updated to 21H1.

•   I am not using Google Drive on the Desktop: I always click to:
[drive.google.com] in order to upload or download.

•   My laptop has 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD, Intel i7 8th gen processor.

•   I am NOT doing any synchronization with any other device. These settings are OFF.
Googledrivesync.exe DOES NOT RUN on my laptop.

•   Going offline happens even when I use the Microsoft EDGE browser. I haven't tried Firefox yet.

•   I have OFFLINE DOCS setting turned off all the time.

•   I don’t use Google Docs.

•   I have reset all my Chrome/Google Drive settings to default, and it still goes offline.

•   My internet connection is 300 mbps, and I am the only user of this connection.

•   Besides my laptop, the only other device using this internet connection is my smartphone on WiFi.  My smartphone is rarely used to surf the internet, as I prefer using my laptop for all internet related activities.

•   When I visit and upload/download to/from any other website, I never go offline.
I must have some incorrect setting on Google Drive.

Screenshot of the OFFLINE message from Google Drive follows:

[image: OFFLINE message screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify 'going offline'. Does the actual download continue, or does it stop as well? Do you become unable to browse other websites in the same browser? How about _other_ browsers? Are you still able to access Internet through other, non-browser programs (such as `ping`)? Is your smartphone able to access Internet?

Comment: This is most probably an internet problem. Maybe your ISP accidentally blocked GDrive. Also maybe you could be going over the storage limit of your plan (free account has 15GB). 
Also it could be a problem from Google's end.

You might want to check by logging in with a VPN or something, and see if it solves the problem. I also faced a similar issue with YouTube thumbnails. My ISP accidentally blocked them, and I couldn't see them (I could watch the video). They later fixed it.

If VPN works, then its a problem with the ISP, if it still doesn't work, then its either laptop or google.

Comment: Thanks user1686 -- Offline -- is a pop-up message from Google drive, a small black rectangle stating Offline and lost functionality.  Then my laptop is completely unable to access the Internet, the dwonload is stuck but the router is up:  my Roku streamer (wired connection) and smartphone (WiFi) continue to function without issues.  All 3 browsers experience the exact same message with Google Drive: EDGE, Chrome, Firefox.  I get the internet back on my laptop only when I reboot the router.  I can no longer upload or download with Google Drive.

Comment: The [tag:google-drive] is for questions about the deprecated installable client, [su] hasn't a tag for the web app as they are off-topic here but the problem looks to be caused by a faulty Internet connection, so it doesn't belong to [webapps.se].

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the problem is caused by the Internet connection.

According to [Enterprise networking for Chrome devices](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/3339263?hl=en) (this is the first relevant googling result that I found) your connection is in the minimal bandwidth range (0.2 - 0.5 Mbps) for editing Google Drive documents.

> **Bandwidth considerations**
> The amount of network bandwidth you need depends on how the Chrome devices will be used. For general web browsing and editing Google Drive documents, 0.2-0.5 Mbps per concurrent session at a minimum should provide satisfactory performance.

It's very likely that a better Internet connection will help. Try using an Internet connection with a bigger bandwidth or by using Google Drive for Desktop.